# What encoding should be used when we make a downloadable file from a J2EE Modern Web App?

Tags: java, csv, web-applications, encoding

I 'm working on Mac Os with Eclipse Kepler on a JSF java project .

How to make a file downloadable for a Windows, Mac Os, Linux environements without misinterpreted characters because of encoding and plat-forms ?

Do we need to check which os the client use to adapt encoding with user-agent parsing ?

If you use UTF-8 , it will be ok on Unix Based Os, but how to make it open simply in windows with excel?

I write this code to export in UTF-8. But it will misinterpreted é & è in Excel.

```
FacesContext fc = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
ExternalContext ec = fc.getExternalContext();

ec.responseReset();
ec.setResponseContentType("text/csv"); 
ec.setResponseCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");

String fileName = "CleanOmicsTracer_Tableau_"+type+".csv";

ec.setResponseHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""); 

// Now you can write the InputStream of the file to the above OutputStream the usual way.

BufferedOutputStream csvOut = new BufferedOutputStream(ec.getResponseOutputStream());  
BufferedWriter csvWriter = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(csvOut, "UTF-8"));

        csvWriter.append("Etude;Identifiant Analyse;Numero d'inclusion;Identifiant Prelevement;Identifiant Extrait;Technologie;Service;Sous-analyses;Categorie;Date Enregistrement\n");

        for (AnalyseDispatcher aAnalyse : viewedListAnalyse) { // somethings is your List<Something>

            csvWriter
            .append(toCsvField(aAnalyse.getSample().getParticipant().getProject().getStudy_name()))
            .append(';')
            .append(toCsvField("A"+aAnalyse.getId()))
            .append(';').append(toCsvField(aAnalyse.getSample().getParticipant().getId_study()))   .append('\n'); 
         } 
         csvWriter.flush();
         csvWriter.close();
         csvOut.close();

         fc.responseComplete(); 
        }
```

Comment: You mean just any kind of file? Or just a text file?

Comment: Apparently a CSV file.

Comment: yep a csv in my case.

Answer (score 0):

What is the source of the CSV character stream?

- A file?
- A blob in a database?

You need to make sure that the `java.io.Reader` that is reading the file uses correct encoding (ie the initial file's encoding).

Comment: I retrieved data from a mysql dataBase which is encoded as vDEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci; And then i tried to make a csv file that you can download in browser by a click ( the file is created when you click) and the response is    ContentType("text/csv");  CharacterEncoding("UTF-8");Header("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"" + fileName + "\""); I use in the BufferedOutputStream and BufferedWriter to write the ouput as a file.

Comment: Show me the code that gets the database value into a String. I'm assuming you are using a `java.io.Reader` somewhere?

Comment: I update the function that i call when i want to make the ouput and download the file.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
ec.setResponseContentType("text/csv;charset=UTF-8");
```

or

```
ec.setResponseContentType("application/csv;charset=UTF-8");
```